# How to make sure owl carousel loads first on page, before other content

Tags: wordpress, owl-carousel

I'm getting a flash of page content below my main slideshow carousel (owl carousel) before the carousel itself loads.  How can I make sure the carousel is loaded FIRST on the page, before the page renders the rest of the content? This is a WordPress site.

http://www.fitzgeraldpetersen.com/

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Can you make the box that holds the owl html to be fixed height or min-height (via style attribute or minimal inline css)? Maybe even a background loader gif in that top box with background-position: 50% 50%;

Comment: Can you set the height for the container first? so that the page doesn't do the push down on load.

Comment: Thank you... I added height:100vh to the div, which is getting rid of the flash of content... but now I have a large gap underneath the slideshow and above the content below. Thoughts on how to get rid of the space? I tried a negative margin on the div below, but it doesn't work at different browser sizes.  Sometimes the content below will be underneath the slideshow.  Also, side now, how to mark an answer as correct, to give credit? Thank you!